# Securing single page application

Tags: ajax, single-page-app

I developed a web application in single-page application (SPA) architecture using Ext JS as client interface, but I have a trouble defining the right way of securing it with AJAX queries. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you reading [OWASP AJAX Security Guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines)